# best practice php array and RAM usage

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, memory

I have 12 mysql db table like table1, table2,....table12. each table has 200,000 records. each record includes country, user-type, package column. i want to get a statistic of above 3 column. to do it, first, i am creating array. then using the array, i am getting the stat data.

```
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
{
   $query="SELECT `country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM `table$i`";
   $result=mysql_query($query);
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
      $country= $row['country'];
      $usertype= $row['usertype'];
      $package= $row['package'];

      $stat_array[$country][$usertype][$package]= 1 + $stat_array[$country][$usertype][$package]
   }
}
```

It take lot of time to get result. Is this a best way to get statistic? please advice me a good method. also, will this use more RAM memory. i need a way to get with less memory usage

Thanks in advance

Comment: How much RAM does it use? How much do you want it to reduce by? What have you tried?

Comment: thank you sir for your quick reply. i didn't check the usage of ram. i need a best way to get statistac with less ram usage

Comment: if you didn't check the usage then how would you even know if you did something to use less ram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12 queries? Just notice, that there is `UNION` command in `SQL`.
Try out this:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
   $query=($i>1?'UNION ALL ':'')."SELECT `country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM `table$i` ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
// other code below
```

Comment: that dont solve memory issue, but lowers processing time in many times.

Comment: Dont use UNION, but UNION ALL. You want to count all the records from all the tables. UNION will discard duplicate rows in seperate tables.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems here is because you have all in the same function php does not delete the memory allocated by the variables. Thus you overwrite/create a new row, ... .

You would need to unset row, country, usertype and package at the end of the while loop. That should help memory wise (at least up until PHP 5.3 I had similar problems when iterating through huge asses of data rows). Another problem is the stat_arr variable as it creates 1 array field for each combination of the 3 fields in the database. Worst case is you have 200k of entries. Which will take up a lot of ram by itself.

Furthermore from what I see you only want to count those 3 coloumns. That could be done differently:

Use (I don't know how you called your ID/primary field thus I'm calling it id in the following code):

```
$Query = "SELECT count(id) AS c_u_p_statistics,`country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM `table$i` GROUP BY `country`, `usertype`, `package`";
```

That way you wouldn't have to sum them up manually but could do so via SQL (which is more efficient most of the time).

Comment: iterate mysql results set does not contribute to huge memory consumption, and unset the $row does not help to reduce memory consumption by a lot

Comment: From my experience with php prior to PHP 5.4 it is so that at least a few bytes still exist if you don't unset prior to reusing the variable with the next row. I had a few small memory leaks that way in the past (very small), but as I iterated through 1-2 mio rows it accumulated to a few megabytes of total memory leak.
(When I used unset at the end of the loops the leaks disappeared).

Comment: lol ... i dun think this is making sense, sorry if i'm too naive. the each iteration just set again the existing variable, how is it contribute to the additional memory?

Comment: I had a memory leak in the past (php 5.2 and 5.3) where I couldn't find the reason after a couple of tests and also trying unset I found out that the problem occured just with the $row parts when I used no unset at the end of the while loops. 
I know that it sounds illogical (especially if one thinks about how garbage collection there should work) but back then it was the only thing that helped close a few small (2-7 bytes) memory leaks that accumulated over a few milion rows of data to quite huge leaks.Maybe someone else knows the reason for this phenomenon there.

Comment: is hard for me to believe this, i been using 5.3, and handling 20 millions of result iteration, and i never get into this problem, maybe you are in different ways, for example, an additional function call for each iteration, pass by references .. etc

Comment: Interesting. A few of the locations in the code where I had the problem back then I had function calls (with similar phenomenon thus I used unset also there on each variable that was not used for the return value), but else there were also a few locations in the source without any function calls and only plain get data from db, do calcs and write them into another table in the db (pure mysqli in the code). There I also had the problem.

If I have time I'll try it out again (don't have the original source any longer since that was at my old job).
(not having to unset would be nice)

Answer (score 1):

Its all in the query. The query below will give you a result with the count per country, usertype and package. Obviously you can use a loop to create the 12 table unions, but for readability I wrote it down in total.

Also keep in mind to use UNION ALL and not just UNION. If you use UNION duplicate rows will be discarded, but if table 1 has a count of 100 for a certain group, and table 2 also has 100 for the same group, you want to return 100 twice, so the sum is 200. If you use UNION it would return 100 once and the sum would obviously be 100 aswell.

```
SELECT SUM(cnt) as total, `country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(country) as cnt, `country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM table1 GROUP BY `country`, `usertype`, `package`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(country) as cnt, `country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM table2 GROUP BY `country`, `usertype`, `package`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(country) as cnt, `country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM table3 GROUP BY `country`, `usertype`, `package`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(country) as cnt, `country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM table4 GROUP BY `country`, `usertype`, `package`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(country) as cnt, `country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM table5 GROUP BY `country`, `usertype`, `package`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(country) as cnt, `country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM table6 GROUP BY `country`, `usertype`, `package`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(country) as cnt, `country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM table7 GROUP BY `country`, `usertype`, `package`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(country) as cnt, `country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM table8 GROUP BY `country`, `usertype`, `package`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(country) as cnt, `country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM table9 GROUP BY `country`, `usertype`, `package`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(country) as cnt, `country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM table10 GROUP BY `country`, `usertype`, `package`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(country) as cnt, `country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM table11 GROUP BY `country`, `usertype`, `package`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(country) as cnt, `country`, `usertype`, `package` FROM table12 GROUP BY `country`, `usertype`, `package`

) temp
GROUP BY `country`, `usertype`, `package`
```

On a side note: You dont have to do

```
$stat_array[$country][$usertype][$package]= 1 + $stat_array[$country][$usertype][$package];
```

you can just do:

```
$stat_array[$country][$usertype][$package]++;
```

And finally if you use a multidimensional array like you have, internally it will have to do a lot of checks. Simply put it will first find the right country in the array which will give another array. It will locate the usertype in that array and then do the same thing again in the third array for package.

If $country, $usertype and $package are all strings, you could beter join the strings and use that.

```
$key = $country.'_'.$usertype.'_'.$package;
$stat_array[$key]++;
```

But I guess it all depends on what you want to do with the data once you have it stored in the array. If its just printing the total count, you dont even need the array but print directly in the query result loop.

Comment: Why would it kill it? This is what the union operator is for.

Comment: that's assuming under reasonable amount of rows

Comment: That's assuming the correct indexes are made. In this case one on `country`, `usertype`, `package` together.